# How to call function arguments one by one

Tags: ruby, currying

I have a Ruby file to generate test result report. In that I have defined so many variables like Test case name, version number, then module1 result, then module 2 result and end result.

Now I make that as a function with arguments as all variables. Another Ruby file needs to call arguments one by one. Means in the starting of Testcase.rb, I will be writing testcase name = Test1; then version number as0.1. Then when module1 runs I will update the result as pass or fail then similarly for module2. But I don't know how to call arguments one at a time.

These are the variables in my report.rb = tc_name, version, tester, login_result, checkout_result, signout_result.

In my test case i have to pass value one by one. Please help.

Comment: Are you using Ruby 1.8 or Ruby 1.9? (The answer varies based on what capabilities are built into Ruby.)

Answer (score 2):

This idea is called '[currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)'.
Googling for 'ruby currying' will give you lots of hits.
Check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095049/how-to-implement-currypartial-function-in-ruby) for some examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Ruby 1.9, perhaps this meets your needs:

```
report = ->(tc_name, version, tester, login_result, checkout_result) do
  puts <<-ENDOUTPUT
       Test Case: #{tc_name}
         Version: #{version}
          Tester: #{tester}
       Login Res: #{login_result}
    Checkout Res: #{checkout_result}
  ENDOUTPUT
end

test1 = report.curry["Test1"]
v12   = test1["v1.2"]
me12  = v12["Phrogz"]
me12["Success"]["Failed"]
#=>    Test Case: Test1
#=>      Version: v1.2
#=>       Tester: Phrogz
#=>    Login Res: Success
#=> Checkout Res: Failed

v13   = test1["v1.3"]
me13  = v13["Phrogz"]
me13["Success"]["Success"]
#=>    Test Case: Test1
#=>      Version: v1.3
#=>       Tester: Phrogz
#=>    Login Res: Success
#=> Checkout Res: Success
```

Alternatively (and perhaps less confusingly) you could instead keep track of a hash of keys. Once you have accumulated all the keys you need, you can do something with them; otherwise you just merge any new data into the hash and pass it back. This provides the same partial-application benefits as the above, and also lets you accumulate the variables in any order:

```
def report(data={},more={})
  data = data.merge(more)
  if data.key?(:tc_name) && data.key?(:version) && data.key?(:tester) &&
     data.key?(:login_result) && data.key?(:checkout_result)
    puts <<-ENDOUTPUT
         Test Case: #{data[:tc_name]}
           Version: #{data[:version]}
            Tester: #{data[:tester]}
         Login Res: #{data[:login_result]}
      Checkout Res: #{data[:checkout_result]}
    ENDOUTPUT
  else
    data # send the newly-merged data back to the user
  end
end

test1 = report tc_name:"Test1"
me    = report test1, tester:"Phrogz"
v12   = report me, version:"v1.2"
report v12, login_result:"Success", checkout_result:"Failed"
#=>    Test Case: Test1
#=>      Version: v1.2
#=>       Tester: Phrogz
#=>    Login Res: Success
#=> Checkout Res: Failed

v13 = report me, version:"v1.3"
report v13, login_result:"Success", checkout_result:"Success"
#=>    Test Case: Test1
#=>      Version: v1.3
#=>       Tester: Phrogz
#=>    Login Res: Success
#=> Checkout Res: Success
```

However, there's no need for the function to merge the values in and accumulate data. You can do this yourself in simple hashes:

```
BAD_LOGIN   = { login_result:"FAILED" }
ALL_GOOD    = { login_result:"OK", checkout_result:"OK" }
ME          = { tester:"Phrogz" }

def report(data)
  puts <<-ENDOUTPUT
       Test Case: #{data[:tc_name]}
          Tester: #{data[:tester]}
       Login Res: #{data[:login_result]}
    Checkout Res: #{data[:checkout_result]}
  ENDOUTPUT
end

report ME.merge(tc_name:"Test1").merge(BAD_LOGIN)
#=>    Test Case: Test1
#=>       Tester: Phrogz
#=>    Login Res: FAILED
#=> Checkout Res: 

ok = {tc_name:"Test2"}.merge(ME).merge(ALL_GOOD)
report ok
#=>    Test Case: Test2
#=>       Tester: Phrogz
#=>    Login Res: OK
#=> Checkout Res: OK

report ok.merge( checkout_result:"CAUGHT FIRE(!)" )
#=>    Test Case: Test2
#=>       Tester: Phrogz
#=>    Login Res: OK
#=> Checkout Res: CAUGHT FIRE(!)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will paste my code hear. If you can give a simple or small idea how to call variable by variable it will be so greatful.